# How exactly do we bind an attribute name to a location in OpenGL?

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I am using OpenTK, a wrapper for .NET. The version of OpenGL used is 4.5 implemented by NVIDIA. I am using Windows 10 Pro.

## Issue

My issue is simple. I want to address the vertex attributes by their names, instead of hard coding their location in shader source.

I have a vertex shader called **basicTexturedVert.glsl**

```
#version 450 core

in vec4 position;
in vec2 normal;

uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

out vec2 vs_uv;

void main(void)
{
    vs_uv = normal;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix * position;
}
```

## Things I have tried

Now to do that, normally I would have to do a GL.GetAttribLocation with the name of the attribute in the program and it would return the location of it. Well I tried everything but it only returns the location of the `in vec4 position` and not of `in vec2 normal`. And by everything I mean:

- When I hard code the location of both attributes, `GL.GetAttribLocation("position")` always returns the correct location, but the same for `normal` returns a `-1`.
- I thought it had to do with the name of `normal`, maybe it is a reserved word by OpenGL, so I changed it to a random word like `abcdef` still gives same result.
- Now I am thinking maybe it has to do with the order of declaration of the shader attributes in the shader source, so I move `normal` before `position`, still same results.
- About now I am going insane trying to figure why OpenGL is always giving the right location for `position`. I thought maybe `vec2` (which here is the only differentiator between the two) is not an accepted type, I check online, damn well it is accepted.

As you can see I tried many things before trying this one. I read that you can programmatically bind the attributes to names and assign a location to choose. So that is what I do here in the following code.

First I create my Shader objects like this:

```
var basicTexturedVertexShader = new Shader("Basic Textured Vertex Shader",
                ShaderType.VertexShader,
                File.ReadAllText(@"Components\Shaders\Vertex\basicTexturedVert.glsl"),
                new[] { "position", "normal" }
                );
var basicTexturedFragmentShader = new Shader("Basic Textured Fragment Shader",
                ShaderType.FragmentShader,
                File.ReadAllText(@"Components\Shaders\Fragment\basicTexturedFrag.glsl")
                );
```

As you can see, each shader gets assigned:
 - A name so I can understand which shader I am working on (during debug)
 - The type of the shader (`VertexShader` or `FragmentShader`)
 - The shader source code
 - And optionally an array containing the names of the shader attributes like for the first one `new[] { "position", "normal" }` which will be assigned to a location during program linking

I then create a program and link them to it:

```
_texturedProgram = new ShaderProgram(basicTexturedVertexShader, basicTexturedFragmentShader);
_texturedProgram.Link();
```

Now inside the `_texturedProgram.Link`:

```
int location = 0; // This is a location index that starts from 0 then goes up
        foreach (var shader in _shaders) {
            DebugUtil.Info($"Attaching shader {shader.Name} of handle {shader.Handle} of type {shader.Type} to program {_handle}");
            GL.AttachShader(_handle, shader.Handle);
            // If the shader we attached has attribute names with it
            // It means we need to give them a location
            if (shader.AttributeNames != null)
            {
                foreach (var shaderAttributeName in shader.AttributeNames)
                {
                    _attributeLocation[shaderAttributeName] = location;
                    GL.BindAttribLocation(_handle, location, shaderAttributeName);

                    // We check if anything wrong happened and output it
                    ErrorCode error;
                    bool errorHappened = false;
                    while ((error = GL.GetError()) != ErrorCode.NoError) {
                        DebugUtil.Warning($"Problem during binding attrib location of {shaderAttributeName} of {shader.Name} to {location} in program {_handle}. Error: {error}");
                        errorHappened = true;
                    }
                    if (!errorHappened) {
                        DebugUtil.Info($"Shader attribute \"{shaderAttributeName}\" of {shader.Name} of program {Handle} SHOULD HAVE BEEN bound to location {location}");
                    }
                    location++;
                }
             }
          }

          // We link the program
          GL.LinkProgram(_handle);

          // Make sure the linking happened with no problem
          var info = GL.GetProgramInfoLog(_handle);
          if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(info)) {
             DebugUtil.Warning($"Info log during linking of shaders to program {_handle}: {info}");
          }
          else {
             DebugUtil.Info($"Program {_handle} linked successfully");
          }

          // We compare the locations we think have been assigned to the vertex attributes
          // to the one that are actually stored in OpenGL
          foreach (var attribute in _attributeLocation) {
                DebugUtil.Info($"[Program:{_handle}] According to OpenGL, {attribute.Key} is located in {GL.GetAttribLocation(_handle, attribute.Key)} when it is supposed to be in {attribute.Value}");
          }

          // We clean up :)
          foreach (var shader in _shaders) {
              GL.DetachShader(_handle, shader.Handle);
              GL.DeleteShader(shader.Handle);
          }

          // No need for the shaders anymore
          _shaders.Clear();
```

And here is the console output:

[image: ConsoleOutput with location=0]

Lets say that `position`'s default position would have been `0` and it just a coincidence. Let's set `location` starting index at like `5`.

[image: ConsoleOutput with location=5]

As you can see, my code works for `position` but not for `normal`...

Comment: Is `vs_uv`used in the next stage (likely a fragment shader)? If not, the compiler may optimize out the whole attribute `normal` as if it had never existed. Thus, no location for it.

Comment: OH. MY. GOD. How can you guys guess it so quickly??! I feel like crying. 
THANK YOU you delivered me from my suffering.

On a more serious note, how do they expect us to know this? ugh

Comment: Knowledge from experience. In your case, the clue was you said "OK for position, wrong for normal". So I followed 'normal' and applied my experience.

Comment: I have to admit, that answer would also have occurred to me but only *after* I'd posted a question about it.

Comment: @MehdiSaffar: "*My issue is simple. I want to address the vertex attributes by their names, instead of hard coding their location in shader source.*" No, you don't. You're going to hard-code *something* into the shader source. It's either going to be an integer location or a string. I see no reason why a string should be preferred over an integer.

Comment: @NicolBolas Right, but I still prefer refering to the vertex attributes by their name. So that in the shader source I do not have to qualify their location.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that, because the `normal` vertex attribute leads to no use in the subsequent stage (= fragment shader), the OpenGL optimizes the shader program by getting rid of unused variables.

Thanks to @Ripi2 for pointing that out.